# Google maps stopped to show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My code is below. Everything was working just fine. Now the maps don't show up. Didn't change anything on the website. Any ideas?

**Error:**

```
InvalidValueError: handleApiReady is not a function
```

**Code:**

```
<form...>
    <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude" value="<?php echo $latitude;?>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude" value="<?php echo $longitude;?>" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&callback=handleApiReady"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map=null;
        var myLatlng=null;
        function handleApiReady() {
            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.318890, -16.494598);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                draggable: true,
                title: 'Fotos',
                icon: '//google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/factory.png', 
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
                document.getElementById("latitude").value = this.getPosition().lat();
                document.getElementById("longitude").value = this.getPosition().lng();
            });
        }
    </script>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:379px;height:390px;"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried to put the handleApiReady definition before the maps include?

Comment: The first error is gone but now there is another error: TypeError: a is null

Comment: I took a look at the maps api documentation, looks like the callback has to be named initMap()...check it out here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps_v3

Comment: anyway: TypeError: a is null

Comment: @pecci the callback does *not* have to be called initMap

Comment: @duncan right...user1406271 maybe try copy the maps api documentation sample and test it, after that add your code.

Comment: 1. #map_canvas 2. your script 3.the maps-API

Answer (score 1):

I just had to change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&callback=handleApiReady"></script>
```

to

```
<script async defer src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&callback=handleApiReady"></script>
```

It solved the problem.